# VBA - if cell is empty then skip the sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have code, which put formula into area and it works fine:

```
Private Sub Jeeves_account2_C()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range, C As Range

With Worksheets("Crd_Headers") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column B
    Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & lastrow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

    ' loop through all cells in column B
    For Each C In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(C.Value) Then
            C.Offset(, -1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[2],Jeeves_Cust_list!C[-1]:C[1],3,0),RC[2])" ' use offset to put the formula in column "P"
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

But I would like to add condition, if cell C2 on the sheet Crd_Headers is empty, then skip the whole sub:

```
If Worksheets("Crd_Headers").Cells("C2") = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

So the code looks like:

```
Private Sub Jeeves_account2_C()

If Worksheets("Crd_Headers").Cells("C2") = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range, C As Range

With Worksheets("Crd_Headers") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column B
    Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & lastrow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

    ' loop through all cells in column B
    For Each C In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(C.Value) Then
            C.Offset(, -1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[2],Jeeves_Cust_list!C[-1]:C[1],3,0),RC[2])" ' use offset to put the formula in column "P"
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

But it gives me error message **invalid procedure call or argument**

Could you advise me, what do I do wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply mixed up `Cells` and `Range` object references.

To refer single cell you have two solutions:

```
If Worksheets("Crd_Headers").Range("C2") = "" Then
```

or

```
If Worksheets("Crd_Headers").Cells(2, "C") = "" Then
```

Comment: ore use the column number instead of `"c"`so make it `.Cells(2,3)